# No callback when using FB.ui to share a link on cellphone

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the code below to open a share dialog:

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'share',
        href: 'http://domain/page.html'
    },
    function (response) {
        // Do something...
    }
);
```

The callback function get called on Windows and Android tablet but not on Android cellphone.

On a Windows PC, FB.ui opened a in-page dialog. When I clicked 'Post', the dialog is closed and callback function is called.

On Android tablet(MI Pad, with Android 4.4.4 and Chrome 46.0.2490.76), Fb.ui opened a new browser tab with the share dialog. When I clicked 'Post', the tab is closed and callback function is called.

On Android cellphone (HTC One M7, with Android 5.0.2, Chrome 47.0.2526.76), Fb.ui opened a new browser tab with the share dialog. When I clicked 'Post', the tab is NOT closed, callback function didn't get called, either.

Is there anything wrong or it's a bug of Facebook? How to make it work on cellphone?

Comment: what exactly do you want to do in the callback function? it´s quite possible that facebook removes it completely sooner or later, because you should not need to care if the user shared something or not.

Comment: Well, the code above is copied from official document, and I didn't notice there is any word about deprecation.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Comment: that´s just my opinion, i know it´s from an official document ;)